# Python3 Json location data extract

Tags: json, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, urllib, urlopen

Hi guys Thanks for all your great advise. I usually find something to help so this is my 1st question. After many long hours, I managed to get a useable response back from this code. Many of the articles don't apply to python3.

```
import re
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import hashlib
import uuid
#! /usr/bin/env python

try:

    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://ipinfo.io/json")

#result = html(buf.decode('utf-8'))

print(html.read())
```

The response came in this form.

```
b'{\n  "ip": "84.0.23.49",\n  "hostname": "cpc127884-ldry4-2-0- 
cust47.know.cable.virginm.net",\n  "city": "London",\n  "region": 
"UK",\n  "country": "GB",\n  "loc": "54.9971,-7.3073",\n  "org": 
"AS5089 Virgin Media Limited",\n  "postal": "BT34",\n  "timezone": 
"Europe/London",\n  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"\n}'
```

I don't know if it's my location or internet service or if its the RPi or maybe this is the new format. Btw I changed some location details. But none of the articles seem to describe how to get the information when it's in this form. It usually looks different. I'm getting lots of errors when I try - telling me the data is binary and not str for example
How would I get my location or city from this "dictionary?"

Answer (score 1):

Use `json.loads()` function to parse the json response (you will get Python dict):

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://ipinfo.io/json")
d = json.loads(html.read().decode('utf-8'))
print(d['city'])
print(d['loc'])
```

Prints (in my case):

```
Bratislava
49.041,17.2512
```

Comment: I get the following error:- 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/testcall.py", line 19, in <module>
    d = json.load(html)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: @KevinLynn I updated my answer (I'm using Python3.6, maybe there's some differences with Python3.5)

Comment: I tried to repeat for location - Traceback
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/testcall.py", line 20, in <module>
    lscity = json.loads(html.read().decode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I repeat what you did for location. It works - but when I try to make 2 variables one for city one for loc it fails with the above error

Comment: @KevinLynn See my edit. You don't want to read from `html` variable again. Just use the dictionary `d` with correct key.